# Stuck on writing a print function to convert and print binary to decimal with syscalls on NASM for x86-64 Linux system

Tags: linux, assembly, decimal, x86-64, nasm

I'm still new to assembly code on  NASM for x86-64 Linux system and I'm trying to write a program which converts the number stored in rdi to decimal so it can be printed. I'm unsure how to write a proper function that will divide by 10 in a loop that uses the remainder as the digits for example: the number 165 stored in rdi will be divided 165/10 repeatedly and the remainder is 5, etc. and the digits output would look something to 0000000165. Any feedback would be appreciated!
Here's my attempt:

```
section .data

BUFLEN:     equ                25
buf:     times BUFLEN db    0    

section .text

global _start
_start:

    mov rsi, 1
    mov rdi, 453265682
    call printnum  
    
    mov     rax,  60 
    mov     rdi,  0 
    syscall

printnum:

   mov r10, 10


  convert:
        
        mov rdx, 0
        mov rax, rdi
        div r10
        add r15, rdx
        cmp rax, 1
        jnle convert
        
        
    mov    rax,   1         ; = 1
    mov    rdi,   1             ; = 1
    mov    rsi,   buf                ; add of buffer to print
    mov    rdx,   BUFLEN             ; num of bytes to write
    syscall

    ret
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many parts in your code that I want to change, but here is a minimal fix to just make your code work.

Below

```
mov r10, 10
```

add

```
mov r15, 9
```

Erase

```
add r15, rdx
cmp rax, 1
jnle convert
```

and change it to

```
mov rdi, rax
add rdx, '0'
mov [r15 + buf], dl
dec r15
jns convert
```

This is the full `printnum` function with the fix.

```
printnum:
    mov r10, 10
    mov r15, 9

    convert:
        mov rdx, 0
        mov rax, rdi
        div r10
        mov rdi, rax
        add rdx, '0'
        mov [r15 + buf], dl
        dec r15
        jns convert
        
    mov    rax,   1
    mov    rdi,   1
    mov    rsi,   buf
    mov    rdx,   BUFLEN
    syscall

    ret
```

It's up to you to think why this works and yours doesn't.

Comment: Thank you so much. The conversion part was what I was struggling on and Now I can see why. I also have a question about the line "mov [r15 + buf], dl " and how it works especially 'dl', if you don't mind answering.

Comment: @Pamh_Tly The `rdx` register's 32-bit part is called `edx`, 16-bit part is `dx`, 8-bit high part is `dh`, and the 8-bit low part is called `dl`. It was originally just `d`, but then Intel extended this to 16-bit `dx`, where you can access the high 8 bits with `dh` and the low 8 bits with `dl`. Later this was extended to 32-bit `edx` and again to 64-bit `rdx`.

Comment: @Pamh_Tly `mov [r15 + buf], dl` means `buf[r15] = dl` if you know C.